# can't set width of label tag in CSS in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

I'm having the following HTML

```
<input type="checkbox" asset="AAA" name="assets[AAA]" value="AAA" id="assets[AAA]" class="c_green" checked="checked">
<label for="assets[AAA]"></label>
```

In CSS I have

```
input[type=checkbox].c_green {
    display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox].c_green+ label:before {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    width:1em;
    height:1em;
    border: 2px solid #66BC29;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:1em;
}
input[type=checkbox].c_green:checked + label:before {
    content:"\2713";
    display: block;
    font-size:1em;
    color:#66BC29;
}
```

After that in safari green label (that is drawn after hidden checkbox) has no width if checkbox in not checked (`value=""`) and not visible. Still it's all ok in Chrome and FF.

What us wrong in above CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of **display: block** try using **display: inline-block** for label

In Css

```
input[type=checkbox].c_green {
     display:none;
}
input[type=checkbox].c_green+ label:before {
     content:"";
     display: inline-block;
     width:1em;
     height:1em;
     border: 2px solid #66BC29;
     text-align: center;
     line-height:1em;
}
input[type=checkbox].c_green:checked + label:before {
     content:"\2713";
     display: inline-block;
     font-size:1em;
     color:#66BC29;
}
```